# What are the conditions required for $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{a}{b}) = \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{c}{d})$ where a, b, c, d are functions of x?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I think I have solved it for the special cases $a = c$ (the solution is $ka = bd(b-d)$) for arbitrary constant which just involved using the quotient rule factoring out $\frac{da}{dx}$ and $a$ eventually getting to $$\frac{a'}{a} = \frac{g'h^2-h'g^2}{gh^2-hg^2}$$
$$\ln|a| = \ln|gh^2-hg^2| + k_1$$

and for the special case $b=d$ (the solution is $a-c = kb$) by similar methods

I have tried the same method on the general case but there is nothing to factor out and I get stuck at $$b^2(c'd-d'c)=d^2(a'b-b'a)$$

I came across this problem after seeing a video with $$(\frac{1}{1-x})' = (\frac{x}{1-x})'$$ as the thumbnail and decided to see how much I could generalise it

I'm hoping for non-trivial solutions if they exist

Comment: $\frac ab - \frac cd =$ constant

Comment: I'm hoping for non-trivial solutions if they exist

Comment: $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(\frac{a}{b}) = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(\frac{c}{d})$ $\implies$ $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(\frac{a}{b}) - \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(\frac{c}{d})=0$ $\implies$ $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\frac{a}{b} - \frac{c}{d}\right)=0$ $\implies $ $\frac{a}{b} - \frac{c}{d}$ is (locally) constant